# Rewrite url with web.config for multiple variables in query string

Tags: iis, web-config, friendly-url

I am trying to make frindly URLs using web.config, and it must rewrite from 1 to (possibly) 2 variables and ignore rewrite if it's a directory name. So I have this URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/2014/ - Where 2014 is a folder.
http://www.domain.com/2014/publications/ - It's one of the possible URLs
http://www.domain.com/2014/publications/news/ - Another possible URL
```

While the real URLs  would be

```
http://www.domain.com/2014/
http://www.domain.com/2014/?page=publications
http://www.domain.com/2014/?page=publications&subpage=news
```

I am trying this web.config but I am getting an error 500.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Friendly 2">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/2014/index.php?page={R:1}&subpage={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />                  
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!